# open a file and read data from file in python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join('\Users\timot\Downloads\LAB EXERCISE 1-20220331\Data', 'ex1data1.txt'), delimiter=',')
X, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]
```

This is my codes that try to open a file in the directory.

This is the error I got:

```
 Input In [1]
    data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join('\Users\timot\Downloads\LAB EXERCISE 1-20220331\Data', 'ex1data1.txt'), delimiter=',')
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How should I fix this code as I am new to python?

Comment: Use a raw string (prefixed with the letter `r`) for strings that contain back slash \ characters. For example, `r"\Users\timot"`.

Comment: Ty using a raw string so the backslash is treated as literal

Answer (score 0):

slash() is an escape character in python.

Use a raw string (prefixed with the letter r"") for strings that contain back slash () to ignore these characters.

```
For example, 

r"\Users\timot\..."
```

Comment: Your response can be better formartted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
'\Users\timot\Downloads\LAB EXERCISE 1-20220331\Data'
```

Do you know how Python reads this? An example is `\t`, that is interpreted as a `tab`, or `\n` which is interpreted as a newline. Try to use a `raw-string` instead:

```
r'\Users\timot\Downloads\LAB EXERCISE 1-20220331\Data' # This works properly
```

or to escape the `\` backslashes

```
'\\Users\\timot\\Downloads\\LAB EXERCISE 1-20220331\\Data'
```